# Filtering WordPress oEmbed provider list

Tags: php, wordpress, oembed

How would I filter the WordPress oEmbed provider list? My aim is to allow just Twitter and Youtube.

**EDIT:** Could I do something like this?

```
function filter_oembed_provider_list( $array ) {
    $array = array( 'http://youtu.be/*' => array( 'http://www.youtube.com/oembed',                     false ) );
    return $array;
}
add_filter( 'oembed_providers', 'filter_oembed_provider_list' );
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Please see the relevant code in class-oembed.php:

```
apply_filters( 'oembed_providers', array(
        '#https?://(www\.)?youtube\.com/watch.*#i'           => array( 'http://www.youtube.com/oembed',                     true  ),
        'http://youtu.be/*'                                  => array( 'http://www.youtube.com/oembed',                     false ),
        'http://blip.tv/*'                                   => array( 'http://blip.tv/oembed/',                            false ),
        '#https?://(www\.)?vimeo\.com/.*#i'                  => array( 'http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.{format}',              true  ),
        '#https?://(www\.)?dailymotion\.com/.*#i'            => array( 'http://www.dailymotion.com/services/oembed',        true  ),
        'http://dai.ly/*'                                    => array( 'http://www.dailymotion.com/services/oembed',        false ),
        '#https?://(www\.)?flickr\.com/.*#i'                 => array( 'http://www.flickr.com/services/oembed/',            true  ),
        'http://flic.kr/*'                                   => array( 'http://www.flickr.com/services/oembed/',            false ),
        '#https?://(.+\.)?smugmug\.com/.*#i'                 => array( 'http://api.smugmug.com/services/oembed/',           true  ),
        '#https?://(www\.)?hulu\.com/watch/.*#i'             => array( 'http://www.hulu.com/api/oembed.{format}',           true  ),
        '#https?://(www\.)?viddler\.com/.*#i'                => array( 'http://lab.viddler.com/services/oembed/',           true  ),
        'http://qik.com/*'                                   => array( 'http://qik.com/api/oembed.{format}',                false ),
        'http://revision3.com/*'                             => array( 'http://revision3.com/api/oembed/',                  false ),
        'http://i*.photobucket.com/albums/*'                 => array( 'http://photobucket.com/oembed',                     false ),
        'http://gi*.photobucket.com/groups/*'                => array( 'http://photobucket.com/oembed',                     false ),
        '#https?://(www\.)?scribd\.com/.*#i'                 => array( 'http://www.scribd.com/services/oembed',             true  ),
        'http://wordpress.tv/*'                              => array( 'http://wordpress.tv/oembed/',                       false ),
        '#https?://(.+\.)?polldaddy\.com/.*#i'               => array( 'http://polldaddy.com/oembed/',                      true  ),
        '#https?://(www\.)?funnyordie\.com/videos/.*#i'      => array( 'http://www.funnyordie.com/oembed',                  true  ),
        '#https?://(www\.)?twitter\.com/.+?/status(es)?/.*#i'=> array( 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.{format}', true  ),
        '#https?://(www\.)?soundcloud\.com/.*#i'             => array( 'http://soundcloud.com/oembed',                      true  ),
        '#https?://(www\.)?slideshare\.net/*#'               => array( 'http://www.slideshare.net/api/oembed/2',            true  ),
        '#http://instagr(\.am|am\.com)/p/.*#i'               => array( 'http://api.instagram.com/oembed',                   true  ),
        '#https?://(www\.)?rdio\.com/.*#i'                   => array( 'http://www.rdio.com/api/oembed/',                   true  ),
        '#https?://rd\.io/x/.*#i'                            => array( 'http://www.rdio.com/api/oembed/',                   true  ),
        '#https?://(open|play)\.spotify\.com/.*#i'           => array( 'https://embed.spotify.com/oembed/',                 true  ),
    ) );
```

Comment: Tell us something more, what do you intend on doing. Since 'to filter' something is in WordPress context unclear

Comment: Apologies, I intend to remove some of the providers. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a built-in function [`wp_oembed_remove_provider`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_remove_provider), respectively [`wp_oembed_add_provider`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_add_provider).

**EDIT**

add to functions.php file

```
function customize_oembed() {

    //load oembed class
    require_once ABSPATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'wp-includes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'class-oembed.php';

    //get a singleton object
    $oembed = _wp_oembed_get_object();

    /**
     * Forget about those lines
     *
       //empty the providers list
       $oembed->providers = array();

       //add what you want
       wp_oembed_add_provider( 'http://site.com/watchvideo/*', 'http://site.com/oembedprovider' );  
    */

    //use applying a filter
    $providers = array(
        'youtube' => array( 'http://www.youtube.com/oembed', false), 
        'twitter'=> array( 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.{format}', true  )
    );
    $oembed->providers = apply_filters('oembed_providers', $providers);
}
add_action('init', 'customize_oembed');
```

**EDIT 2**

I looked into it, and I found out, that you can use a filter `oembed_providers` exactly in the same way, as it is used in a constructor of the class. Therefore using additional wordpress functions, which would again try to require the class file and instantiate a singleton object, is useless, when you can do it in one function.

(Despite of the fact, that it works, i still do not get a usage of this filter :-D)

**EDIT 3**

Finally, I got it working.

It is really similar code to yours, though the argument in the function is basically useless. It only gives you original providers, which you want to override, so you are not using it and you can return an array directly.

Maybe the important thing to remember is, after editing your list, you need to update your posts, since wordpress is saving some data into table `*_postmeta` under key `_oembed_…`

```
function filter_oembed_provider_list( ) {
    return array( 'http://youtu.be/*' => array( 'http://www.youtube.com/oembed', false ) );
}
add_filter( 'oembed_providers', 'filter_oembed_provider_list' );
```

Comment: I am aware of the function although I'd prefer to filter the list because each time WordPress adds a new provider to the list which they will do regularly, I'll have to add another wp_oembed_remove_provider

Comment: In simple terms, you want this list to be cleared and then add twitter and youtube?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I need. Without editing the core of course.

Comment: This seems to work, thanks, although I'd still be interested to know how to filter that array. Do you know how?

Comment: Somebody else might have a new insight, but from my perspective it seems, that there is not another solution. Yet the two manipulation functions are done like my reply. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/media.php#L1335

Comment: Thanks Ivan, your help much appreciated. I've +1'd your answer but won't set the answer as accepted in case somebody can help with the filtering. I'm just interested now :)

Comment: FYI, Saving the post didn't clear the oembed cache for me. I had to do the things the hard way by running this query: delete from wp_postmeta where meta_key like '_oembed_%'; use at your OWN risk. Also, I'm using the filter with just return array(); to disable all the providers.

Answer (score 1):

If the filter you provided (`oembed_providers`) is working for you, then you might try something like this:

```
/**
 * Filter the oembed providers through a whitelist
 *
 * @param array $providers
 * @return array $providers
 */
function filter_oembed_provider_list( $providers )
{
    // edit the whitelist to your needs
    $whitelist = array( 'youtu', 'twitter' );

    $output = array();

    foreach( $providers as $key => $provider )
    {
        foreach( $whitelist as $allowed )
        {
            if( stristr( $key, $allowed ) )
                $output[$key] = $provider;

        }
    }
    return $output; 
}

add_filter( 'oembed_providers' , 'filter_oembed_provider_list', 99 );
```

where you must edit the `$whitelist` to your needs.

### Update:

Thanks to @Ivan Hanák, for suggesting the post saving part ;-)

This snippet should now work, after you update the oEmbed cache, by saving the post ;-)

Comment: May I ask why you're un-setting providers? We're filtering the constructor so I don't think any have been set yet. I could be wrong?

Comment: I just wrote the code directly from your question without any more information ;-) So you think the oembed_providers filter isn't suitable in your case? The idea was to unset all providers array items not containing youtube or twitter etc.

Comment: The oembed_providers filter is certainly suitable. That is exactly what I'm looking to do. I have edited my question with my thoughts on how i'd like to filter. Problem is, it doesn't work.

Comment: Strange, your updated example looks good to me, it sounds like this filter is useless ;-) I can see that _wp_oembed_get_object() contains the instantiation of the class via $wp_oembed = new WP_oEmbed(); so I would have thought that the constructor would activate the filter!

Comment: I still quite do not get this filter. Never mind. Take look at my updated edit. It turned out, you can assign own provirders like it was initiated in the class, through the filter; therefore emptying of the original array is useless.

Comment: So, after some digging I got the filter working. See my third edit. @henrywright your code works after all, all work required to get it working is to update a particular post.

Comment: @IvanHanák thanks for the edit. The way I am assuming it should work is 1: I write my filter function and hook it to oembed_providers. 2. When WP runs, it applies all filter functions such as the one I've wrote. 3. Any instance of the WP_oEmbed class will run my filter function because apply_filters is in the class constructor. I just don't get what I'm doing wrong in my filter_oembed_provider_list function.

Comment: " I just don't get what I'm doing wrong in my filter_oembed_provider_list function." Did you check out my third edit? I tried to explain that. At least, now it works for me.

Comment: +1 @IvanHanák, great digging ;-) I just tested my filter snippet and it finally worked after I saved the post ;-)

Comment: @IvanHanák you nailed it! A 'post save' needed was the issue! Thanks for all of your help looking into the problem! and thanks to birgire too for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need, as instagram Oembeds are broken in Wordpress before 4.4.
what I realized is that the filter for the providers run before your Theme is initialized, so if you want to add this filter, you have to use a plugin.This is what I used

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Fix Instagram oEmbed
 * Plugin URI: https://10up.com
 * Description: Fix Instagram oEmbed.
 * Author: 10up
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author URI: https://10up.com
 * License: GPL2
 */

namespace TenUp\Plugin\InstagramFix;
add_filter( 'oembed_providers', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\oembed_providers' );


function oembed_providers( $providers ) {
    if ( ! isset( $providers['#https?://(www\.)?instagr(\.am|am\.com)/p/.*#i'] ) ) {
        $providers['#https?://(www\.)?instagr(\.am|am\.com)/p/.*#i'] = array(
            'https://api.instagram.com/oembed',
            true
        );
    }
    return $providers;
}
```

so you must

1) create a folder like instagram-oembed-fix in the plugin folder
2) create a file named instagram-oembed-fix.php
3) copy over the php code above
4) activate your plugin ( network activate in a network )
5) regenerate oEmbed cache by going to any post and presing "Save"