# Remove YouTube embedding with wp_oembed_remove_provider()

Tags: wordpress, youtube

I am trying to remove YouTube embedding from some of my WordPress output, so it only shows the link.

I have tried the following code without any luck.

```
wp_oembed_remove_provider('#http://(www\.)?youtube\.com/watch.*#i'); 
wp_oembed_remove_provider('#https://(www\.)?youtube\.com/watch.*#i');   
wp_oembed_remove_provider('#http://youtu\.be/.*#i');    
wp_oembed_remove_provider('#https://youtu\.be/.*#i');

echo apply_filters("the_content", $result->text);
```

What am I doing wrong? And how am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you're at a point where it's too late to remove the providers. Try hooking into `plugins_loaded` or `init`:

```
add_action( 'init', 'so26743803_wp_oembed_remove_provider' );
function so26743803_wp_oembed_remove_provider(){
    wp_oembed_remove_provider('#https://youtu\.be/.*#i');
    // etc.
}
```

Edit (untested): unsetting providers with the `oembed_providers` filter (see [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19466374/1981996)):

```
add_filter( 'oembed_providers', 'so26743803_oembed_providers' );
function so26743803_oembed_providers( $providers )
{
    unset( $providers['#http://youtu\.be/.*#i'] );
    // etc.

    return $providers;
}
```

Comment: If I add this code, it will work for all outputs, right? I want it to only apply to certain outputs.

Comment: what do you mean with outputs? posts? post types?

Comment: So, under what conditions should the providers be removed?

Comment: In my plugin, the post body should in some cases show without the auto-embedding on YouTube links. So it should have all filters, except YouTube.

Comment: some cases.. which cases?

Comment: It should send out the post as an e-mail, and HTML embedding like YouTube seems to be erased from most e-mail providers. All code is ready, but the embedding is removed. So I want it to be links only.

Comment: Might be a better idea to filter the providers, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/19466374/1981996 . Define the callback function somewhere in your plugin's main file or in an include, and insert the `add_filter()` part where you echo the `$result->text` part.

Comment: I have already looked at that question, but I'm having a hard to figuring out how to include it in my code. If you have a good solution, please insert it as an answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with an untested example. By the way, an important thing that was mentioned in that SO Q&A is that "you need to update your posts, since WP is saving some data into table `*_postmeta` under key `_oembed_`"

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I have nothing under the key `_oembed_`, and my post is is saved in a custom table with a standard INSERT query.